# Why is null<>null=null in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am going through a tutorial for MySql, and I came through the following query.

```
mysql> select null <> null;
+--------------+
| null <> null |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
```

I did not understand why the result is Null, it needs to be either 1 or 0 I think (based on results from other comparison operators)?

Why it is giving the result as Null.

Thanks,

Comment: NULL is neither equal to nor not equal to anything else. Not even NULL!!! It's like saying is butter bigger or small than 4?

Comment: Yeah, `<>` is like that in MySQL, use the null safe equal `<=>` : "NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL."

Comment: `SELECT NOT ISNULL(null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because any comparison operator over `NULL` appearing in in a sql filter should (and does) make the row not be selected.

You should use null safe operator `<=>` to compare to column containing `NULL` values and other `NOT NULL` value but `<=>` will return `1` when both operands are `NULL` because `NULL` is never considered equal to `NULL`.

**This is an example of a situation where null safe operator is useful:**

You have a table:

```
Phones
----
Number
CountryCode (can be NULL)
```

And you want to select all phone numbers not being from Spain (country code 34). The first try is usually:

```
SELECT Number FROM Phones WHERE CountryCode <> 34;
```

But you notice that there are phones with no country code (NULL value) not being listed and you want to include them in your result because they are nor from Spain:

```
SELECT Number FROM Phones WHERE CountryCode <=> 34;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select null <> null;
```

Here `<>` is not `null safe operator`. It is `Not equal operator`. 
Refer [official website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) of mysql.
`Null safe operator` is `<=>`