# MySQL else if - wrong else condition?

Tags: mysql

I have to do something like:

```
if(@new_siren == null) 
{
 do something...
}
else
{
 do something with '@new_siren != null'...
}
```

and it's MySQL code, which is not working properly. It's checking if @new_siren is null, but else is like separate closure. Even is @new_siren is null I am in 'else' condition.

```
IF(@new_siren = null)
THEN
    IF(@myClient like 'Requis')
    THEN
        CALL tmp_update_myReport(client_oid, 'C');
        CALL tmp_update_myStatut(client_oid, 'Erreur');
    END IF;
 ELSE
    IF(@new_siren NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$')
    THEN
        CALL tmp_update_myReport(client_oid, 'B');
        CALL tmp_update_myStatut(client_oid, 'Erreur');
    ELSE
        IF NOT(select luhn_(LEFT(@new_siren,9),9))
        THEN
            CALL tmp_update_myReport(client_oid, 'A?');
            CALL tmp_update_myStatut(client_oid, 'Erreur');
        END IF;
    END IF;
 END IF;
```

Comment: why not use the `IS NULL` synatax for example `if(@new_siren IS NULL)` then ....else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare a NULL using `=` operator. You should use `IS NULL`.
`NULL= whatever` is always false.

Look at this question:
[Why is null<>null=null in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855477/why-is-nullnull-null-in-mysql/23855490#23855490)