# Query not returning values for NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a bit of trouble with a query for SQL Server 2008.

I have a table with some values and a category. This category can be e.g. Stock, Bond or NULL.

Then I may want to see everything in my table that is not bonds:

```
SELECT Value, Name, Currency, Assetclass
FROM MyTable
WHERE Assetclass <> 'Bond'
```

Here I expect to see all my assets that are Stock and uncategorised (NULL). But instead I only see the stocks. I get the same result as setting my Where-condition to Assetclass = 'Stock'.

I am aware that NULL is treated as an unidentified value, but I would expect it to only disregard rows that contain exactly 'Bond' and keep everything else, but this is apparently not the case?

Comment: `WHERE (Assetclass <> 'Bond' or Assetclass Is null)` ??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty -> This will not work - I am interested in selecting everything except the few rows where the assetclass actually contains 'Bond'

Comment: @Steffen: It will work. It will select all non-null values except bond (satisfies the `Assetclass <> 'Bond'` condition) *as well as* all null values (satisfies the `Assetclass is null` condition).

Comment: @DavidHedlund I agree it should, but I received a lot of unexpected rows using this and can't really explain why.
EDIT: Ah forgot the parenthesis ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is the expected behavior. If you don't want to do an `OR` you could always replace null with something else in your comparison:

```
WHERE ISNULL(Assetclass, 'Anything but Bond') <> 'Bond'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behaviour.

You are asking for all the rows that have a value that is different from 'Bond'.

`NULL` is not a value but a 'marker' stating that the system have no clue about the content of that field; being the content unknown the system cannot say for sure that the value is different from 'Bond' hence the row is not returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare `NULL` values using `<>`, you should change your SQL to:

```
SELECT Value, Name, Currency, Assetclass
FROM MyTable
WHERE Assetclass <> 'Bond' OR Assetclass IS NULL;
```

In MySQL you have null safe comparators but that is not the case in SQL Server.

The idea is that NULL is not a value, therefore it can't be compared to other values. However, you can check if a field is NULL using `IS NULL`.

Please, check this question for more insight: [Why is null<>null=null in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855477/why-is-nullnull-null-in-mysql/23855490#23855490)

Answer (score 1):

Projection will ignore null values. Use Isnull function

```
SELECT Value, Name, Currency, Assetclass
FROM MyTable
WHERE Isnull(Assetclass,'')  <> 'Bond'


OR 


SELECT Value, Name, Currency, Assetclass
FROM MyTable
WHERE Assetclass is null or  Assetclass <> 'Bond'
```

I would prefer the first approach